# AJAX Script doesn't respond until background program ran with exec() ends

Tags: php, ajax, exec, background-process

I run a background PHP program with `exec()` like this :

```
exec('/usr/bin/php bgScript.php "arg1" "arg2" > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

It works and the program does run in background.

### Problem

I have **Output Buffering Enabled** and would like to keep it that way.

My whole script is this :

```
exec('/usr/bin/php bgScript.php "arg1" "arg2" > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
echo json_encode(array(
  "status" => "started"
));
```

When an **AJAX** request is made to the file above, the process is started and is in background. I assume this because, further requests to the server returns data and doesn't `wait` for the previous AJAX script to finish.

But, the problem is that the **JSON data is not outputted until the background process is completed**.

Since the program is made to run in the background, shouldn't the JSON Data be outputted without waiting for the `exec()` to end ? I don't know how to say this techinically (Forgive me) : Why does the Output Buffer continue until `exec()` ends ?

How can I make the script output the JSON Data right after the program is started in the background and close the connection between the AJAX script and browser ?

Answer (score 0):

The command does not run in the background if it's stdio is not redirected. From the official documentation

> Note:
>   If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

There are several methods to alter this behavior in Unix like systems you can run the command with `command >/dev/null &` on windows you can use `start command`.

Comment: The command indeed runs in the background as further requests to the server are not being waited.